# How to store setting at User Level?

Tags: community, user, customsetting, user-management, sfdc-styleguide

I have a requirement to showcase a detail page having multiple Accordion sections which are closed by default. Now there will be a checkbox which will allow the user to make sure that all the Accordion sections are open by default. So I have to store this checkbox value at user level, or you can say for each user.

The problem is I want to store this checkbox value without creating a custom field at User level. As the setting is as per each user, So how can we store this information at user level, whether the user wants the Accordion sections to be open by default or closed?

Answer (score 3):

Use one of those two below:

- Hierarchy Custom Settings
- Separate custom object where records are identified by user id (it doesn't even need to have lookup to User object)